# Finding the mean of right-censored values

Tags: bootstrap, censoring

I wanted to check how fast an average colleague of mine is able to complete a puzzle, so I ran some experiments. The problem is they weren't done in exactly 50 minutes, I always got bored and moved on to the next person. Hence my data is right-censored at 50. Let's say it looks like this:

```
Aaron: 34
Betty: X
Cecil: X
Dave: 18
Elias: 47
Fredric: 39
Greta: 37
Howard: X
Ingrid: X
Joy: 29
Kristine: 34
Lou: 32
Margret: X
Nigel: 40
```

An `X` means that they did not complete it in 50 minutes.

How do I use this data to find how fast on average person in my company is in completing the puzzle? To be more clear: How do I find the mean or the median of the above data with a bootstrap confidence interval? I don't want to just throw out the data where the person did not complete the task within 50 minutes, but I don't know how to incorporate those data points in my analysis.

Comment: The mean can abviously not be computed without further assumptions and the median should be no problem, as long as less then half of the population has no `X`.  Just replaxe `X` with a very large number (if you are doing this in `R` I suggest `Inf`) and compute the median. Depending on the number of `X` you might also consider a trimmed mean.

Comment: @Bernhard. Thanks. It may happen that more than half of the population has 'X'. Does that mean that I cannot draw any conclusions?

Comment: Intuitively, without math, what do you expect the mean of $(3, 5, 9, X, X, X, X, X, X)$ to be? More or less then $20$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interval regression on a constant, since you have a mixture of point data, which can be expressed as $[t_1,t_2]$ where $t_1=t_2 < 50$, and right-censored data, where completion time is $[50,+\infty)$. In this case, the expected duration is 43 minutes, instead of the 40 you get from ignoring the right-censored folks. This model relies on the error being normally distributed with mean zero and homoskedastic variance. This is the sort of strong parametric assumption that Glen_b is rightly concerned about.

Here's the example in Stata:

```
. clear

. input str8 name str2 time

          name       time
  1. "Aaron" 34
  2. "Betty" X
  3. "Cecil" X
  4. "Dave" 18
  5. "Elias" 47
  6. "Fredric" 39
  7. "Greta" 37
  8. "Howard" X
  9. "Ingrid" X
 10. "Joy" 29
 11. "Kristine" 34
 12. "Lou" 32
 13. "Margret" X
 14. "Nigel" 40
 15. end

. 
. gen t1 = cond(missing(real(time)),50,real(time))

. gen t2 = cond(missing(real(time)),.,real(time))
(5 missing values generated)

. intreg t1 t2, nolog

Interval regression                             Number of obs     =         14
                                                   Uncensored     =          9
                                                   Left-censored  =          0
                                                   Right-censored =          5
                                                   Interval-cens. =          0

                                                LR chi2(0)        =       0.00
Log likelihood =  -40.91248                     Prob > chi2       =          .

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   43.20936   4.073829    10.61   0.000      35.2248    51.19391
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsigma |   2.634876   .2589092    10.18   0.000     2.127423    3.142329
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       sigma |   13.94158   3.609604                      8.393212    23.15773
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you still want to boostrap, that can also be done:

```
. bs, reps(100): intreg t1 t2, nolog
(running intreg on estimation sample)

Bootstrap replications (100)
----+--- 1 ---+--- 2 ---+--- 3 ---+--- 4 ---+--- 5 
..................................................    50
..................................................   100

Interval regression                             Number of obs     =         14
                                                   Uncensored     =          9
                                                   Left-censored  =          0
                                                   Right-censored =          5
                                                   Interval-cens. =          0
                                                Replications      =        100

                                                Wald chi2(0)      =          .
Log likelihood =  -40.91248                     Prob > chi2       =          .

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   43.20936    4.94787     8.73   0.000     33.51171      52.907
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsigma |   2.634876   .2534669    10.40   0.000      2.13809    3.131662
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       sigma |   13.94158    3.53373                      8.483219    22.91203
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Cool, thank you! I was going to experiment with this myself, but I saw that Strata is proprietary software. Do you have any pointers on how I can do this in Python or R?

Comment: Try the `censReg` package in R. This simple case is also called a Tobit model.

Answer (score 3):

The bootstrap (alone) will not help you identify the mean in the presence of censoring, and will not be much use with the median given a dataset like the one you supplied; you may be able to get some kind of lower bound on the median in this case with a bootstrap, but you can do that nonparametrically without the need for bootstrapping.

To estimate the mean would require some kind of parametric assumption*.

If you observe fewer than half the times to completion then the median would have a similar problem.

This is a standard kind of problem in survival analysis; once a suitable parametric distributional model is chosen, estimation is relatively easy with canned routines. I've done this in R; it provides a number of distributions by default but it's possible to add further distributions.

First we create a dataset with time under observation and a column to denote the censoring status (first few rows shown below). Here I fit an intercept-only Weibull model to the times

```
  subject time completed
1   Aaron   34         1
2   Betty   50         0
3   Cecil   50         0
4    Dave   18         1
5   Elias   47         1
6 Fredric   39         1

(weib.fit <- survreg(Surv.puz~1,puzzle,dist="weibull"))
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv.puz ~ 1, data = puzzle, dist = "weibull")

Coefficients:
(Intercept) 
   3.879441 

Scale= 0.3010924 

Loglik(model)= -40.8   Loglik(intercept only)= -40.8
n= 14
```

Here's the Kaplan-Meier survival curve (nonparametric), along with 95% CI, and the fit from the above model:

[image: Plot of Kaplan Meier survival curve with 95% CI and fitted Weibull, showing fitted median and mean]

The sample median is 39.5, the fitted median is 43.34, the fitted mean is 43.43. You can see from the nonparametric CI that we can get a lower bound on the median without a parametric assumption (where the horizontal green dots hit the vertical black dashes) but there's not a large enough proportion of complete times to get an upper bound on the median. The parametric fit can provide CI-type bounds on both the mean and median (though I haven't given any here).

You could try a variety of parametric assumptions if you don't want to be too reliant on any one assumption, but you're still reliant on whatever set of distributions you consider -- there's no way to avoid *some* assumption about the upper tail beyond what you observed.

* well it might be possible to proceed with some assumption that sufficiently regularizes the problem without being fully parametric (obtaining some set of bounds, presumably), though I am not sure right now what form that assumption might take.

Here's the code that I used. First read in and set up data:

```
puzzle <- read.table(stdin(),colClasses=c("character","numeric"),
             na.strings="X",sep=":",col.names=c("subject","time")) 
Aaron: 34
Betty: X
Cecil: X
Dave: 18
Elias: 47
Fredric: 39
Greta: 37
Howard: X
Ingrid: X
Joy: 29
Kristine: 34
Lou: 32
Margret: X
Nigel: 40

 puzzle$completed <- as.numeric(!is.na(puzzle$time))
 puzzle$time <- with(puzzle,ifelse(is.na(time),50,time))
```

Then load the survival library and create the required survival object,
fit the Weibull and plot the curves etc

```
 require(survival)
 (Surv.puz <- with(puzzle,Surv(time,event=completed)))
 (weib.fit <- survreg(Surv.puz~1,puzzle,dist="weibull"))

 plot(survfit(Surv.puz~1),xlim=c(0,100))
 lambda <- exp(weib.fit$coefficients)
 k <- 1/weib.fit$scale
 f <- function(x) pweibull(x,k,lambda,lower.tail=FALSE)
 curve(f,0,100,col="blue",add=TRUE)
 weib.mean <- lambda*gamma(1+1/k)
 weib.median <- lambda*log(2)^(1/k)
 puz.median <- median(puzzle$time)

 abline(h=c(0,1),col="darkred",lty=3)
 segments(0,.5,max(weib.median,puz.median),.5,col="green4",lty=2)
 segments(weib.median,0,weib.median,.5,col="green4",lty=2)
 segments(puz.median,0,puz.median,.5,col="green4",lty=2)
 arrows(weib.mean,-.03,weib.mean,0,length=0.05,col="green4")
 c(data.median=puz.median,weib.median=weib.median,weib.mean=weib.mean)
```

Comment: +1 I... I just can't help it! The white background of graphs clashes really hard with the faint graph-paper background of the site... I am repeatedly compelled to edit graphs for transparency... there's probably a 12-step program for this kind of thing. ;)

Comment: @Alexis Well, I'll leave it as it is for your sake, but personally I prefer the white background to having the page background showing through -- it's not enough to bother me, but I like the "clean paper" look of the white background on plots. On my monitor the difference is pretty subtle though.

Comment: How are you able to get the diagram and the data (sample median and fitted median) using the above R code?

Comment: I didn't show every bit of R code I used, but this can be worked out from the parameters estimates above using information in the help of the relevant functions. In terms of the parameterization of the Weibull given at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), $\hat\lambda=\exp(\tt{Intercept})$ and $\hat{k}=1/\tt{Scale}$, from which the maximum likelihood estimates for the median and mean may be computed by substitution. You can draw a Weibull survivior function via a simple call to `pweibull`. The Kaplan-Meier 'curve' is drawn via `plot.survfit`.

Comment: ... I only kept the code a few days; I'd have to regenerate it from scratch. Actually, I see a small error in my copy of your data, which I will also fix. (now done. Apologies to Alexis; I'll try to fix up the transparency later.)